# Power Automate Stop Process

Tags: power-automate, kill-process

I have a flow with in between a step that waits for Incoming mails.

I would like to stop this process after 30 minutes and subsequent after stopping it, send a mail.

[image]

Do you have an idea. See also the attachment.

Regards

Fischer